# "python3" command not doing anything

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x, shell

When I run the `python3` command, nothing happens. No stdout, no stderr... nothing. When I try the `python2` command, however- I get the expected result. What is going on?

```
ubuntu@ip-172-91-23-255:~$ python3
ubuntu@ip-172-91-23-255:~$ 
ubuntu@ip-172-91-23-255:~$ which python3
usr/bin/python3
ubuntu@ip-172-91-23-255:~$ python2
Python 2.7.12 (default, Nov 19 2016, 06:48:10)
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

Comment: You could try `which python3` to see if python3 is symlinked to something other than a python interpreter.

Comment: Yep. Just thought of that. Added that to the main question. Is "usr/bin/python3" the expected output?

Comment: Yeah that's what i would expect. Now try `ls -la /usr/bin | grep python3`. That will show what it's actually symlinked to.

Comment: @mario_sunny That is reasonable. What do you get for `which python2`? Is it also in `/usr/bin`?

Comment: I get `python3 -> python3.5` but executing `python3.5` does nothing either, and `python3.5` does not appear to be linked to anything.

Comment: I get `usr/bin/python2` when I execute `which python2`

Comment: Seems like i would trying reinstalling python3. Or you could try running python through a debugger like gdb but I doubt I would be able to help much interpretting whatever you find.

Comment: it seems to have enviornment variable issue or try re installing python 3 to a different directory

Comment: Don't use `which` to find out about a command. It ignores aliases and functions. What happens if you invoke python3 by supplying the path explicitly?

Comment: What does `type -a python3` say?

Answer (score 0):

Just solved the same issue

1. If you renamed the python executable change it back, else, ignore this.
2. add the folder of python3 instalation to the PATH,

   - the instalation folder is possibly
     this: `C:\Users\RV420\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32`
   - To add folders to your path you can just search 'environment
     variables' on windows, then click on environment variables and find
     one called path
3. Now make sure that the new folder comes first in the path that the Python2 instalation folder
4. You're good to go